# Xamarin PushAsync method not supported

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, async-await, zxing

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24621814/pushasync-is-not-supported-globally-on-android-please-use-a-navigationpage-xa/37244322) thread and a few others about similar errors, but unfortunately I still don't understand how to fix my problem.

I have a method that should open a `ZXScannerPage` so that I can read QR codes

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        var scanPage = new ZXingScannerPage();
        scanPage.OnScanResult += (result) => {
            // Stop scanning
            scanPage.IsScanning = false;

            // Pop the page and show the result
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                Navigation.PopAsync();
                DisplayAlert("Scanned Barcode", result.Text, "OK");
            });
        };

        // Navigate to our scanner page
        await Navigation.PushAsync(scanPage); // Here is the error            
    }
```

I need to use this function before my `await Navigation.PushAsync(scanPage);` call

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(<Something goes here>);
```

But I am unsure where this should go, and what arguments I should feed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PushAsync` method is not supported because MainPage of the app is not `NavigationPage`.

Create page in which overrides `OnAppearing` method. In this method use your code.

When application started in App.xaml.cs or App.cs depends on project type, call in constructor

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new YourPage());
```

This will call `OnAppearing` method in your page and your code push the scanner page up.

**EDIT**
U can use your scannerPage like

```
var scanPage = new ZXingScannerPage();
scanPage.OnScanResult += (result) => {
            // Stop scanning
            scanPage.IsScanning = false;

            // Pop the page and show the result
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                Navigation.PopAsync();
                DisplayAlert("Scanned Barcode", result.Text, "OK");
            });
        };
MainPage = new NavigationPage(scanPage);
```

In this case after scan is completed Navigation.PopAsync() will not work because in navigation stack is only one page (except NavigationPage).

Comment: Ok thanks, so I will need to make a new class called YourPage.cs as well/

Comment: @BarneyChambers Yes. Add new Page, not class (or just create class and inherit from Page).

Comment: should this be my `scanPage` which is made during `var scanPage = new ZXingScannerPage();`

Comment: @BarneyChambers Yes, but your Navigation.PopAsync(); will not work, because it is just one page in navigation stack. So maybe its better when you create new one.

Comment: Sorry I am confused, I thought I was making a new page when I used `var scanPage = new ZXingScannerPage();`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to know how to initialize and use Navigation page functionality,

Before using PushAsync and PopAsync functionality you need to initialize a new Navigation Page with some page in your app.

> MainPage = new NavigationPage(Something goes here);

You can set Navigation Page as your main page in App class using some base page in your app i.e. Login page or Welcome page

```
public class App : Application
{
  public App()
  {
    var nPage = new NavigationPage(new WelcomePage()); // or new LoginPage()
    MainPage = nPage;
  }
}
```

Now that you have initialized a Navigation Page with some basic page, you can Push or Pop other pages i.e. your scan page.